# Problem with formatting response from API in React and adding it to the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code in the file 'Search.js'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'

class Search extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      query:'',
      searchedBooks:[],
    }
  }
  updateQuery=(query)=>{
    this.setState(()=>({query:query.trim()}))
    this.finder(query.trim());
}
finder=(query)=>{
  BooksAPI.search(query)
  .then((responses)=>{
    let myvar=[]
    responses.map((response)=>
    myvar.concat([{
      name:response.title,
      author:response.authors,
      img_url:response.imageLinks.thumbnail
    }])
    )
    console.log(myvar);
    this.setState({
      searchedBooks:myvar
    })
  })
}
 render(){
   const query=this.state.query;
      const {handleSearch}=this.props;
        return(<div className="search-books">
        <div className="search-books-bar">
          <button className="close-search" onClick={()=>handleSearch()}>Close</button>
          <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" value={query} placeholder="Search by title or author" onChange={(event)=>{this.updateQuery(event.target.value)}}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search-books-results">
          {this.state.searchedBooks.length!==0 ? JSON.stringify(this.state.searchedBooks): JSON.stringify(this.state)}
          <ol className="books-grid">
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>);
    }
}

export default Search;
```

My goal is to get the responses from the API and store them in a formatted manner into the state which can be seen in the 'finder' function. The responses from API are clearly visible in the console but console.log(myvar) just before this.setState in finder function gives no response meaning something is wrong while formatting the response. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map method iterates over the elements of an array with a given function and returns a new array. In your case, you should be returning the formatted data from the map.

```
myvar = responses.map((response) => {
  name: response.title,
  author: response.authors,
  img_url: response.imageLinks.thumbnail
})
```